# Wrong date stamped in my passport on leaving the US. Would this cause problems for future visits?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program

Hoping someone could please help. I visited the US in 2015 for 2 weeks in August and I only noticed last year that the return stamp on the passport was put down as November which would mean I visited the States for 4 months approximately.

I am visiting the States again this December for 3 weeks and my ESTA was accepted. I am just wondering if the previous stamp showing 4 months will be an issue? If so, how can I amend this? I just feel that the IMO may see the passport when I get to the States and ask how I stayed 4 months on an ESTA when it is for 90 days.

Could someone please help?

Comment: What return stamp? The US does not stamp passports on exit.

Comment: What is the "return stamp"?

Comment: You can check your arrival and departure dates to and from the US here. If it shows a 2 week stay you will be fine. https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search

Comment: I don't mean to be insulting, but are you sure the date is not in American format (MM/DD/YYYY)?

Comment: Its a stamp which says "Department of homeland security- Customs and Border protection" and below it has my entering date "Aug 17 2015" and below that it says "Nov 14 2015"

Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: That's not your exit date, that's the 90-day limit date you got when you arrived. Aug 17 -> Nov 14 is 90 days (not 4 months).

Comment: The question is clear and answerable, downvotes are not warranted.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't seem like there should be any issue here.

The US doesn't stamp passports on exit, so no part of that shows how long you've been in the country. There is no "return stamp." [The stamp](http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/312ea9e97a73434681a0a5859dd7b38d/usa-visitors-passport-visa-stamp-in-an-eu-irish-passport-cb8r6n.jpg) shows the date you were admitted (August 17) and the date you were admitted "until" (the date you had to leave by): November 14. That's permission to stay for 90 days, which is exactly what you'd expect for someone entering under the Visa Waiver Program. You stayed for less, which is fine; nothing requires you to use all 90 days.

As DJClarworth points out, you can [check your I-94 arrival/departure record](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) online. This will show the actual records the US Government has for your stay, and will confirm they know you didn't overstay before.